# CSS + JS - overlay onmouseout child items issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

I'm struggling with an overlay with JS + CSS.
I have 4 boxes and 1 overlay. If I hover with my mouse over one box the overlay is sliding in, and cover all 4 boxes. If I move my mouse out of the overlay, it disappears. This all works well but...
If I add any element to my overlay (text etc), then `onmouseout` is detecting all element, as I left the overlay, and the overlay disappear.
I tried to change many things in CSS but couldn't find out the solution. Also, i read many questions similar to this, but couldn't find the proper one.

Here is my code:

```js
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('overlay').classList.add('mst-popupbox-full-slidein');
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.box {
  background: red;
}

.overlay1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;

}

.inner {
  position: relative;
}

.mst-popupbox-full-slidein {
  animation: slide-in-sm;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

@keyframes slide-in-sm {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

.mst-popupbox-orig {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Libre-Baskerville-Bold' !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<body>
<div class="container bg-light">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row inner p-0 ">
        <div id="overlay" class="overlay1 bg-dark p-0 " onmouseout="off()">
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 inner p-0">
          <div class="p-5 box" onmouseover="on()">
            <div class="mst-popupbox-orig">
              <h1>1</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="p-5">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-0">
          <div class="p-5 bg-danger">3</div>
          <div class="p-5">4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone could help me out with this, would be glad.
Best Regards:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case,to achieve pupose you can use `onmouseleave` instead of `onmouseout`:

```
 <div id="overlay" class="overlay1 bg-dark p-0 " onmouseleave="off()">
     <h1>Hello</h1>
     <h1>Hello</h1>
     <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
```

And `onmouseenter` instead of `onmouseover`:

```
<div class="col-6 inner p-0">
    <div class="p-5 box" onmouseenter="on()">
        <div class="mst-popupbox-orig">
            <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-5">2</div>
</div>
```

Because of the `onmouseout`, `onmouseover` will trigger when the mouse pointer is moved out of an element, or out of one of its children.

*Key to research: bubble (propagate up the document hierarchy)*